# GridBagLayout readd components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I created an `ArrayList` of `JLabel`s of size n and placed the `JLabel`s inside an `JInternalFrame` with the help of a `GridBagLayout` manager so that the grid fits my purpose.

Now I want to replace some of those `JLabel`s or even remove them. 
Removing the k-th `JLabel` does work well with

```
innerframe.remove( ListOfLabels.get(k) );
ListOfLabels.remove(k);
```

(By the way if I'm using only one of those the `JLabel` is not removed from the internal frame -- why ? If I remove other objects like `Checkboxe`s, it sufficies to use only  `innerframe.remove(ListOfCBoxes.get(k));`)

Even the other `JLabel`s stay at their position, what did not work, when I placed the `JLabel`s inside the surrounding `JFrame`.
But I'm not able to readd a `JLabel` after editing it's content. I'm trying

```
//Initialization 

ArrayList<JLabel> ListOfLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>(n);
GridBagLayout GridBLayout_innerframe = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints GridBConstraints_innerframe = new GridBagConstraints();
JInternalFrame innerframe = new JInternalFrame();
innerframe.setLayout(GridBLayout_innerframe);

// Creating components of innerframe, arranging them in a grid and adding them. 
// This seems to work.

innerframe.remove( ListOfLabels.get(k) );
ListOfLabels.remove(k);

labelk = new JLabel("New content");
ListOfLabels.add(labelk);
GridBConstraints_innerframe.gridy = k ;
GridBLayout_innerframe.setConstraints(ListOfLabels.get(n-1), GridBConstraints_innerframe) ;
innerframe.add(ListOfLabels.get(n-1)) ;
```

Of course the same constraints were used for the k-th `JLabel` before and I did not
erase this information. I hoped I can overwrite it.

However the result is that the `JLabel`s that I removed stay removed and the ones I want to 
add do not appear. Even after ''refreshing'' the window. There is also no error message from Eclipse.

Can someone please find my mistake and explain how to readd components into a hopefully already existing grid :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the `JLabel` without saying the `Component` that you did this. You need to call the `revalidate()` method just after adding/removing a `Component` when it's already visible.

So, in case `innerframe` is visible and you called `innerframe.remove(...)`, you need to call:

```
innerframe.revalaidate();
```

Then `innerframe` notices that `Component`s where added or removed and re-assigns the `Component`s that are now in the `Component` (calling the `LayoutManager`, repainting, ...).

Comment: @challenger3 If you have a grid and delete the label in the middle, there will be a hole - do you mean that with your broken layout?

Comment: I'd like to add a picture, but have not enough reputation :D 
So the labels are arranged in a 10 x 3  Grid. 
They all lie in the first column. 
After I used your advise, the JLabel that I readd will spawn 
in a fourth column. O.o 
Also the rows for the removed JLabels seems to be removed, 
since the other labels move up and down, so that they are uniformly distributed in the refreshed window.

Comment: @challenger3 Sure you need some reputation to add a picture, but you can upload the picture to a web service like imgur.com and post the link, this will help me to understand your problem

Comment: @challenger3 And the row you talked about wasn't removed - it now has a size of 0 px so you can't see it. You can avoid something like that with setting an `Insets` object for your `GridBagConstraints`

Comment: Okay. 
this is an example picture of the whole frame before removing: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ldyo5olqpeg6q9/example_1.tiff?dl=0
Then one of the situation after removing:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw0idiv0c0tlqxw/example_2.tiff?dl=0
The new Jlabel containing "upload a picture of this" is placed to the right of the rest.

Comment: @challenger3 Can you post the code (not in the question but in a link) where you add all your components so that I can see what's wrong in your layout?

Comment: @challenger3 In this case I would re-layout the your `Container` like _Sergiy Medvynskyy_ suggests

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to remove/add components in a complex layout. In such cases I would provide a full relayout: clear the container (use the method `removeAll()`) and add all the required components again. Of course you must call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for the top changed container.

Comment: Thanks for the methods, the removeAll() is a blessing for me!
In fact, this was the first thing I wanted to do - the relayout.
I created the innerframe to delete and recreate it. But I wasn't able to manage this :D